# Why my async / await function is not working properly

Tags: javascript, async-await

I have next doubt, I was practicing about async/await functions stuff. I have created a simple test:

```js
console.log('Testing async-await');

main();

async function wait(nSeconds) {
  await setTimeout(function() {
    console.log('Request finished !!');
  }, nSeconds * 1000);
}
async function main() {
  let a = await wait(5);
  console.log('end !!');

}
```

My idea, as long as I understand is simulate with `wait(nSecond)` function a waiting like a ajax request, for example. Everithing is called in `main()` function.

My actual output is :

[image]

But... souldnt be ??? :

```
Testing async-await
Request finished !!
end !!
```

Im telling to my code, `when you get on line 'let a = await wait(5);' just dont continue until end of function is resolved` . So what is happening here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function `wait` should look like this:

```js
function wait(nSeconds){
    return new Promise( resolve => setTimeout( resolve, nSeconds * 1000 ) )
}
```

The setTimeout method does not return promise so await keyword does not work in this case.

Comment: Thank you so much, the point for me was : wait only work on Promises. Thanks so much